# KVC and modern syntax

Tags: objective-c, kvc

Did KVC pick up any of the features of objective-c literals a.k.a. 'modern objective-c'

I'm wondering because it would be really handy if there were something far shorter, and more readable than

`[someObject setValue:someValue forKey:someKey];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably same as you, I was unable to find any information on that

But I think the issue with KVC following "modern objective-c" is that the compiler wouldn't have any way to tell if you referenced a variable that's out of scope, or if you misspelled something.

So I think KVC will always have to follow the standard message syntax

Comment: The compiler doesn't (can't) check the validity of `someDict[aKey]`, either.

Comment: @JoshCaswell +1 And moreover: A different syntax having the same information (object, key, value) can *always* produce the same code. One could think of `v[k]->-->>object`.

Answer (score 2):

Object subscription is close to KVC:

```
someObject[someKey]=someValue;
```

Please note, that object subscription and KVC follows different code paths, so it is possible that the behavior is not the same. However, there is little reason  for that.

Beside this one might doubt, if this is the clearer syntax:

```
object[@"a"]=object[@"b"]=object[@"c"];
```

Which messages are sent?